# Updating column datatype in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update datatype of a column in mongodb dataset, but even after successful run of command expected changes are not reflecting in compass.

query:

```
db.EquityPrice.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.EquityPrice.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {Trade_Date : new Date(doc.Trade_Date) }});
})
```

Can anyone please help to figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is `doc._id` defined? Do you want to use `data['_id']` instead?

Comment: Someone put in significant effort to answer [a recent question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777936/can-we-use-singleton-class-as-an-example-for-singleton-pattern-design-questions), one that you've promptly deleted.... why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels...my mistake that I tried to frame a concern as question. But at the same time whatever mentioned in answer was already part of my question and I don't agree with answer. For example why Serialization or Cloning is issue with Singleton if I do not specify class implements Serializable or Clonable interface. So instead of getting into arguments I thought better to delete the questions. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> db.EquityPrice.find().forEach(function(data) {
>     db.EquityPrice.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {Trade_Date : new Date(doc.Trade_Date) }});
> })
> ```

In your code you are finding all entries in the collection `EquityPrice` and `forEach` element applying a function which has the document (`data`).

The update function which is called for each document expects a query param as first argument. In your case you pass `{_id: doc._id}` - but the object `doc`is not defined and therefore `undefined`. The query doesn't find an element with the `_id` of `undefined`.

You want to update the passed `data` object - therefore change your code to:

```
db.EquityPrice.update({_id : data['_id']}, {$set : {Trade_Date : new Date(data['Trade_Date']) }});
```